# HTML5 Button Styling

Tags: css, html

I am using the following to show a `<button>` for my form.

```
<button id="btnSend" type="submit" style="width: 100%; height:38px; text-indent:-9999px; border:none; margin-top:20px; cursor:pointer; background-color: blue;">
    Send
</button>
```

I want to know how can I set the font color for it? I tried `font-color` and `color` but neither worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your text is being moved all of the way off of the page with the `text-indent` property, so even if you had a color on the font you wouldn't be able to see it.

So remove `text-indent: -9999px` and then add a color - `color: #fff` or whatever color you'd like.

#### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q4prg31q/1/)

Also you are better off defining your styles in CSS rather than inline styles.  So your updated CSS might look like:

```
#btnSend{
    width: 100%; 
    height:38px; 
    border:none; 
    margin-top:20px; 
    cursor:pointer; 
    background-color: blue;
    color:#fff
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this one

```
 <button id="btnSend" type="submit" style="width: 100%; height:38px;  border:none; margin-top:20px;     cursor:pointer; background-color: blue;">
       <font style="color:cyan">Send</font>
    </button>
```